# Cannot Get Express Route to Activate on Localhost

Tags: node.js, express, browser, localhost, react-router

### The Problem

I have a server (node.js) on localhost port 8080, with the client running on 3000. In order to run my web app, I run both concurrently, but only use the server as a proxy for the client to bypass CORS requests - it does not serve any static pages. **I have found that although making API calls from client code to the server works perfectly fine (or a script that makes unirest requests), I cannot test simple routes on the *browser* on localhost:8080/[route]**, such as this one:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log('serving login');
    res.send('login');
})

//on the Google Chrome browser: localhost:8080/login
```

### The Question

The /login route never gets triggered. Is my URL incorrect on the browser? If so, how can I correct it?

#### Side Note

This may/may not change anything, but I am using React Router HashHistory for my client side. Interestingly when I type in localhost:8080/login into the browser, it automatically converts to localhost:8080/login#/.

Comment: Hash is causing you problem. Only localhost:8000/login should work

Comment: I agree, but how do I remove the # symbol from being automatically added? This seems to be the work of React Router, but even after commenting out the render of client static files and restarting with nodemon, somehow the client html still renders and adds the # symbol!